# How to export data from a Thin Plate Spline (TPS) plot in R language?

Tags: r, dataset, export-to-csv

I'm a beginner to **R** and I am trying to extract data in a gridded format from a Thin Plate Spline plot in the **R** language.  Basically I have a data-set of points from across the UK containing the longitude, latitude and amount of rainfall for a particular day.  Using the following code I can plot this data onto a UK map:

```
dat <- read.table("~jan1.csv", header=T, sep=",")
names(dat) <- c("gauge", "date", "station", "mm", "lat", "lon", "location", "county", "days")
library(fields)
quilt.plot(cbind(dat$lon,dat$lat),dat$mm)
world(add=TRUE)
```

So far so good.  I can also perform a thin plate spline interpolation (TPS) using:

```
fit <- Tps(cbind(dat$lon, dat$lat), dat$mm, scale.type="unscaled")
```

and then I can do a surface plot at a grid scale of my choice e.g.:

```
surface (fit, nx=100, ny=100)
```

This effectively gives me a gridded data plot at the resolution of 100*100.  So here are my questions:

1. How do I extract the data from this gridded data set (i.e. actual values) to put in a file such as excel or .txt?
2. How could I change the grid size so the grid starts at a particular x value (and y value) in steps of my choice?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's generally good practice when posting a question to mention which packages are being used to solve a particular problem and to share some sample data showing what you've achieved and where you are stuck. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `predict` function available, a typical strategy would be to use something like:

```
 rnglat <- range(dat$lat)
 rnglon <- range(dat$lon)
 xvals <- seq(rnglon[1], rnglon[2], len=100)
 yvals <- seq(rnglat[1], rnglat[2], len=100)
 griddf <- expand.grid(xvals, yvals)
 griddf$pred <- predict(fit, x=as.matrix(griddf) )
```

(Since `Tps` doesn't use a formula interface and `predict.Krig` doesn't appear to use a `newdata` argument, I'm not making this in a form that would work for most regression problems.) If you want to narrow the range to something less than the full range or change the number of "grid lines", then modify the `seq` arguments. (Tested with the `fit0`-object constructed in the last example on the fields::predict.Krig help page.)

Comment: Thats great - by typing 'griddf' and 'griddf$pred' it gives me the values on a grid of my choice.  Do you know how I could get a surface plot of exactly the same data (i.e. a gridded surface plot using 'xvals' and 'yvals'?).  I tried typing surface(fit,x=as.matrix(griddf)) but this didn't give me the same grid size.